# How to use XmlSerializerFormat in a Restful Webservice?

Tags: wcf

We have created a WCF webservice. We have created two operation contracts like this:

```
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
      [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "getID/{id}")]
    File getID(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "auth")]
    ResponseData Auth(RequestData rData);   }
```

As you can see I have a Get and Post method. This works fine, but if I want to set the response format of my GET service,I have to use XMLSERIALIZERFORMAT tag.If I add this and then try to hit POST service, I get Error:400 "Bad Request Error". How should I set the response of my GET method in the same service.

I have tried adding another service 'Service2.svc' in the project where I have kept only GET methods and 'Service1.svc' has only POST services. In the interface of Service2, i have used XMLSERIALIZERFORMAT but still not able to hit POST service. I think I have to use DATACONTRACTSERIALIZER. But I dont know how to set the attributes in that.

Can anyone please help me out with this?
Thanks
Charan

Answer (score 0):

If you want your GET to send a Response in XML then below setting on your GET method should be enough.

```
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml
```

You dont need to use XmlSerializerFormat. Just try to browse to your service in IE and you should see the response from your GET Method would be in XML format.

Regarding getting a Bad Request on your POST try to see on how the request body is being sent to your method. To see your request body try using tools like Fiddler to inspect your request and response. To debug the cause of Bad Request try enabling tracing on your service.

[How to enable tracing on your Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)